# .Net Web API returns occasionally no response at all if Exception is thrown crashing the application pool

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, webapi

From past 1 week facing the issue, In my application when multiple users trying to login then application is throwing unexpected error sometimes successfully login but if anyone got the exception the whole site is going down. From the log file i have seen that if any exception is coming application stuck there and it keeps on calling the Send Exception API due to which multiple API hit the server and Application pool is getting crashed may be, when we are restarting the IIS Application again starts working. Also from the Log i got to know is that api are sending the request but not getting response.

From the Event Log Viewer i got the following warnings

- 
- 1310

  3

  3

  0x80000000000000

  7135

  Application

  (SERVER NAME)
- 3008

  A configuration error has occurred.

  19/12/2020 9:26:29 PM

  19/12/2020 10:26:29 AM

  3aa223c6527a47ac8eb6f9a55c085afe

  2

  1

  0

  /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-7-132528471879029705

  Full

  /

  C:\MYAPP.WebAPI</Data>

  (SERVER NAME)

  3816

  w3wp.exe

  MYORG\svcMYAPPWebAPI

  ConfigurationErrorsException

  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)

  https://myappwebapi.myorg.com:443/?aspxerrorpath=/api/Email/SendException

  /

  (MY IP ADDRESS)

  False

  MYORG\svcMYAPPWebAPI

  74

  MYORG\svcMYAPPWebAPI

  False

  at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

..................................................................................

- 9009

  0

  3

  0

  0

  0x80000000000000

  86402

  System

  (Server Name)
- C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000062\schema

  12000780

..................................................................................

[From Browser console getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lPUF.png)

[Browser Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEI9Y.png)

......................................................................

From Log Files

SendExceptionEmail System.Web.HttpException (0x80072749): Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.  If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the server name.
at System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.MakeRequest(StateProtocolVerb verb, String id, StateProtocolExclusive exclusiveAccess, Int32 extraFlags, Int32 timeout, Int32 lockCookie, Byte[] buf, Int32 cb, Int32 networkTimeout, SessionNDMakeRequestResults& results)
at System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.DoGet(HttpContext context, String id, StateProtocolExclusive exclusiveAccess, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags)
at System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: According to the description of this error in eventviewer, the dependency of Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel cannot be loaded and used, and is being used by another process. I think it is precisely because multiple users have failed to log in and need to call Send Exception Api to throw exceptions. When a process is calling and another process is calling at the same time but cannot obtain resources, this problem will occur.I suggest you try single-user login first, there will be no dependency being occupied by another process, and this problem should not occur.

Comment: Thanks @Bruce Zhang
for single user it's fine but how can we resolve for multiple logins?

Comment: I'm not sure why the dependency of Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel be occupied by another process. You can use resource monitior to check which process occupy the dependency while multiple user login. But I think you can use lock and await to prevent multiple process. While one process executes code, lock it and do not release method and resource until it finish. Then other process will not conflict.

Comment: @Bruce Zhang Thanks